# Reading a text file from standard input using <

Tags: python

I have a Python script which ends the following way:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
     if len(sys.argv) == 2:
       file = open(sys.argv[1])
       text = file.readline()
       ... #more statements
```

This works when I type in the following: `$ python3 script.py my_file.txt`

However, I want to change it so my script can accept text from standard input (or even a text file). This is what I want to be able to do:

```
$ ./script.py < my_file.txt
```

I think I need to use `sys.stdin.read()` (or maybe `sys.stdin.readlines()`). Could you tell me what I would need to change from my original script?

I'm sorry if this looks very basic, but I'm new to Python and I find it hard to see the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's exactly what you said, you don't need to open a file.

Instead of calling `file.readline()`, call `sys.stdin.readline()`.

You can make it "nice", with something like:

```
file = sys.stdin if use_stdin else open(sys.argv[1])
```

Comment: Would I still need to leave `if len(sys.argv) == 2:`? Or can I delete this part?

Comment: It may be that the flag `use_stdin` should be len(sys.argv) != 2 ;) The flag should be whatever you need to decide between file input or standard input.

Answer (score 0):

Theres a cool module you can use for this! Assuming you want to do processing per line:

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input():
    process_line(line)
```